# problems with adding jMTP API for 64 bit OS

Tags: java, api, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, jmtp

i downloaded jMTP library for java but when i add it like every .jar file i get so many compilation errors so i researched for solutions and i found that the library does not support 64 bit JVM because of dll file who supports only 32 bit, so i switched my JVM to 32bit, much of errors are gone but i still have one error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Jmtp.main(Jmtp.java:14)

notice that their is no syntaxe error, the code who is compiled i get it from Stackoverflow and he works perfectly.

please guys i need your help, any solutions....

Comment: You should search a bit more. There are several jMTP forks. E.g. https://github.com/reindahl/jmtp which contains a file named `jmtp64.dll`. Therefore I assume that 64bit is supported.

Comment: so i have to switch again my JVM to 64bit ? please give me more details how can i add this library github.com/reindahl/jmtp i found a lot of classes i'm gonna use.Thanks

Comment: You can ask for example the author to upload a release zip.